# How to create Day item in coredata in one go for a diary app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Can some body tell me the best way to create the Day entity in Coredata in one go for a diary app?
PS : I know how to make a notes app in which i can insert notes in DB, but if the don't insert notes in a specific day then the day is not shown when fetched.

I can't seem to understand how to put the notes in the respectetive days in core data ?

Comment: You can set an attribute to be of type Date

Comment: @LukeSmith Ok, Can you answer the second problem of how to create them in one go ?

Comment: @AbhishekBiswas can you please elaborate; what does it means one go?

Comment: @msmq I want to create a diary like app. Like when we open the app for the first time then the all the dates are already there.

Comment: We do not understand what you are asking. Please rephrase your question to better understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @AbhishekBiswas I think, it would be better if you pre populate all the days in core data and notes filed will be empty by default; Afterwards, notes will be added as user will enter in any note.

Comment: @msmq Care to explain how to pre populate all the days.

Comment: Prepoulating "all" days is impossible, unless you can tell us on what date the universe will end.

Comment: @TomHarrington So, how can we do it in code for a small set of 10 years  from present time ?

Answer (score 1):

You could insert all the dates at the start by choosing a start date, an end date, and then using `NSCalendar` methods to go from one to the other one day at a time. Add a new entry for each date, and you're done.

That would be a really bad design though. It doesn't make sense to create new entries in your persistent store for every possible day you might cover. Better to only store data that you actually need than to waste time and space for data you'll never use.

To show every day in a week or month or whatever, **show those dates**, don't rely on Core Data to have every possible date. Show every day in the range that your UI covers. Fetch every diary entry for those dates. If there are diary entries on the date, show them. If there are no diary entries for a date, show the date with no entries. Showing every day in a specific range is a function of your controller code. It should choose the dates and ask Core Data what it has for those dates.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you should subclass your entities first so they are easier to work with. And then you could add a function that returns an array of the object (entity) that is your diary. e.g

```
func getData(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [Entity] { 
let request: NSFetchRequest<Entity> = Entity.fetchRequest()

do {
let entityData = try moc.fetch(request)
return entityData
} catch {
// Handle errors
 }
 }
```

You could then add a predicate to this method that returns specific data inside the entity matching the arguments you pass your predicate. I know this doesn't cover your full question but i hope it helps!